# Parallels and virtual firewall appliance between guest and host

Tags: firewall, virtual-machines, local-area-network, pfsense, wide-area-network

I am wondering if it is possible to run a VM (Linux) from Parallels using host only mode in which the VM in question is networked with a second VM/firewall (pfsense) and detached, so to speak, from the host OS (network connectivity exists between the firewall and Linux VMs, not the Linux VM and host OS). The firewall VM/appliance would in turn be networked to the host OS via NATed VLAN.

I'm basically attempting to place a firewall VM/appliance between my host OS and VMs used as dev environments. I'd like to launch all dev environments in a single subnet which takes the role of a WAN interface on the firewall appliance with the main LAN interface NATed with my host OS' network card.

All scenarios I've come across use a single subnet to establish network connectivity between the host OS and each VM. What I'd like to do is establish two separate subnets, have one subnet NATed between host and firewall (LAN), and have an additional subnet tied to the WAN interface on the firewall where all dev environment VMs reside. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

EDIT: Or would the reverse be more logical, WAN subnet between host and firewall, LAN subnet between firewall and dev environments?

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail?  What you're describing sounds very basic.

Comment: What do you mean by "Parallels"?